# Get data from a specific worksheet in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript

I'm using the code below, but I want to get data from a specific sheet. For example Sheet2, Sheet3 ...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var currentQuestion=0;
var totalCorrect=0;
var totalWrong=0;
var response;
function getReply(data) { //Get data from Google Spreadsheet in JSON
    response=data;
}
</script>
<?php
$key = $_GET['value'];
echo '<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/'. $key .'/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=getReply"></script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just a matter of replacing `od6` with the name of the sheet?

See here for example: https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample